# Garbage Collection of Listeners clarification (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Assume the following two classes:

```
public class Network {
   private static Network instance;
   public Network() {
      instance = this;
   }
   public static Network getInstance() {
      return instance;
   } 
   public interface Listener {
       public void event(String msg);
   };
   ArrayList<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

   public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
   }


}


public class Act1 extends Activity implements Network.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        Network.getInstance().addListener(this);
    }
    public void event(String msg) {
       // do nothing
    }
}

public class Act2 extends Activity implements Network.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
          Network.getInstance().addListener(new Network.Listener() {
     public void event(String msg) {
      // do nothing
        }
    );
    }
    public void event(String msg) {
    }
}
```

Will either of the Activities leak once a user moves on to another Activity?  Will either Activity be prevented from getting GCed? Are there any problems with the Listener implementation above?

Answer (score 1):

Your example has some mistakes.

For example you never instantiate Network and every time you instantiate it, the static field will reference another instance. A more proper way to write Network would be the following

```
public class Network {
    private static final Network INSTANCE = new Network();

    private Network() {/*empty*/}

    public static Network get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    //rest of the code ommitted
}
```

However, if you are not removing the Activity instances from the Network singleton (that static field instance in the Network class - assuming you initialize it at some point), then that instance will always have a reference to your Activity objects that were added to it's ArrayList. This way they cannot be garbage collected.

Comment: Sorry the code was more meant to be pseudocode than real world, I forgot to mention that. So if the Activities are still in the ArrayList, do I have to add and call `network.removeListener(this);` when the Activity is paused/destroyed? If that's the case, why do I not see that behaviour with other APIs?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, yes. Which other APIs are you referring to?

Comment: for instance MediaPlayer setOnPreparedListener as a small example.